# How to make <td> change line when content is overflow?

Tags: html, css

Here is the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sAM9g/2/)**. As you can see, I set `width:100px` for the table. Obviously, the present table is not 100px in width because of the long string in  tag.

I've used `overflow:hidden` as well as `word-wrap:break-word`, but no use in this case. Could anyone tell me how to solve this question?

I want the long string to change line when it hits the maxinum of width for table, without adding vertical scrollbar, just increase the current height of `<tr>` tag.

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/HW69D/) what you want?

Comment: Do you want the code in the cell content to be broken at any point, or is it human language text (where language-specific rules should apply)? If it is code, does it really need to be there? The question is not really well-defined unless you specify the type of the “long string” and how it may be divided into several lines.

Comment: Interesting blog post on this topic: http://kenneth.io/blog/2012/03/04/word-wrapping-hypernation-using-css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break), not `word-wrap`:

```css
#convert-result td {
    word-break:break-word;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sAM9g/3/).

Also your `table` element's width is set to `100px` in the code you've provided, *not* `100%`. You'll need to modify this as well:

```css
#convert-result table {
    ...
    width:100%;
    ...
}
```

[**Fixed JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sAM9g/4/).

Comment: Could you give me some detail for the difference between `word-break` and `word-wrap`? Thanks a lot!

Comment: See http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-text/#word-break-property and http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-text/#overflow-wrap-property for official documentation on both.

Comment: Interesting source to read is also MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap

Answer (score 1):

just use break word

```
#convert-result td {
        word-break:break-word;
}
```